# Trying to read the serial output of a SIKO MA502 with pyserial, but getting empty lines

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

I use the Siko MA502 measurement system that is connected via an USB to UART cable from FTDI, to be more specific the TTL-234X-5V. I want to read the distance out the serial output from the measurement device with a python script to put it later in a csv-file. When i run my script i only read empty lines. The problem is that i dont know what im doing wrong. It might be the way i connected the MA502 to the USB to UART cable, but as i said i dont rlly know. I have to add that im pretty new to the topic of python and the ways i have to connect my hardware. The port and baudrate in my script are the right ones, thats the only thing that i know. Hopefully someone can help me.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)#, timeout= 1, bytesize= serial.EIGHTBITS , parity= serial.PARITY_NONE,)

 
ser.flushInput()

ser.flushOutput()

while True:

    data = ser.readline()#.decode('utf-8')

    print(data)
```

Comment: For example, instead of using your own program, why not try using an existing general-purpose terminal communication program?

Comment: I have to use my own programm. Thats a task at work and i need to solve this problem with python so everyone can use the measurement system, without the need of an external programm. @kunif

Comment: Use a terminal emulation program as a sanity check for your setup. As it stands you have too many unknowns, and as you already stated yourself, you don't know what you are doing wrong. So begin by reducing what could be wrong, and temporarily substitute your untested program with a utility program that can handle either text or binary data. BTW what you are calling "*empty lines*" could be the result of a timeout, meaning your program read *nothing*, which is not the same as an "*empty line*".

Comment: @KingBojack I'm not suggesting you change the solution, just suggesting it as a way to see what the problem is. First of all, it is better to check whether communication is possible with commonly used software, and then check step by step whether there is a problem with the software you created. If they have already been done, it would be better to add the situation to the question article. [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)